# Message "Uninstalling...", but no result

Tags: uninstallation, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I can't uninstall an application from my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge. I go to Settings -> Applications -> Application manager, select any application and uninstall. I see a message "Uninstalling..." for a very long time, but no result. Sometimes the phone restarts without any reason during this procedure. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it any system application?

Comment: No, it might be any application

Comment: Did you try to uninstall from Google play store? If you open that app in play store there is a uninstall option.

Comment: Uninstalls fine from play store. Than you! But why no uninstall in regular way?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have a `hard reset` and if that problem occurs again. You can take your device to `Samsung Service Centre`. There can be a virus which would be stopping your device from `uninstalling` any application from your device. Having a hard reset is the best option you have which have a great probability of solving your problem.